# Change date format for the example dates given below date field

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7, with the latest date module release. I've added a date field to an event node type I created.  However, when I go to create a new event, the example date given (the date format description) underneath the date field uses the American date format of m/d/y. I want to change it so that the example date uses the English date format of d/m/y.  Can someone tell me how to do this.  I did change all the date formats in the date format section to UK date formats, but this hasn't made any difference.  I also changed the timezone to Europe, also with no effect.

I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the format in field settings. Follow below steps to change.

- Go to admin/structure/types
- Click on manage fields next to your content type
- Click on edit link next to the field

[image]

Comment: Many thanks Anil, I thought it would be something straightforward

Comment: It might be worth noting that you can add to those "Date entry options" by implementing [hook_date_formats()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_date_formats/) in a custom module.